# How to drop property constraint on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to drop property index on AgensGraph.

```
agens=# create vlabel v;
CREATE VLABEL
agens=# create elabel e;
CREATE ELABEL
agens=# create property index on v ( id );
CREATE PROPERTY INDEX
agens=# create property index on e ( id );
CREATE PROPERTY INDEX
agens=# drop property index on v ( id );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 1: drop property index on v ( id );
                            ^
agens=# drop property index on e ( id );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 1: drop property index on e ( id );
                            ^
```

But, there is some problem on grammar.

How to drop property constraint on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

Name of property index is created automatically at creation time.

You can use '\dGe' and '\dGe' for find structure of labels.

```
agens=# \dGv v
        List of labels
 Graph | Name |  Type  | Owner 
-------+------+--------+-------
 graph | v    | vertex | agens
(1 row)

Vertex label "graph.v"
--
Property Indexes:
    "v_id_idx" btree (id)
Inherits: graph.ag_vertex

agens=# \dGe e
       List of labels
 Graph | Name | Type | Owner 
-------+------+------+-------
 graph | e    | edge | agens
(1 row)

Edge label "graph.e"
--
Property Indexes:
    "e_id_idx1" btree (id)
Inherits: graph.ag_edge
```

After search index name, drop property index next.

```
agens=# drop property index v_id_idx;
DROP PROPERTY INDEX
agens=# drop property index e_id_idx1;
DROP PROPERTY INDEX
```